# Multiple Infowindows for a Single Google Maps Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

Is there a way to create multiple infowindows for a single google maps marker?

For example, if several deliveries are made to the same address throughout the year, can the properties for each of those deliveries be displayed in a scrollable infowindow from that marker?

Otherwise I would end up doing some really dirty AJAX.

In theory I would love to just create an array of contentStrings as shown in the modified example from [Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows). Ideally this would be displayed as a navigable carousel within the infowindow.

```
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });

  **var contentString = ['contentString1','contentString2','contentString3'];**

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

Comment: What trouble are you having implementing that? [Easy enough to do for a single marker with a single infowindow](http://jsfiddle.net/7w4o1s1k/1/).  One other option would be tabbed infowindows which are supported by the [InfoBubble third party library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple proof of concept for a single marker, iterate through the array of strings when a "next" button is clicked:

```js
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString[0] + "<br><input type='button' onclick='next(1);' value='next' />"
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  map.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });
}
var contentString = ['contentString1', 'contentString2', 'contentString3'];
var infowindow;

function next(i) {
  var next = i + 1;
  if (next >= contentString.length) {
    next = 0;
  }
  infowindow.setContent(contentString[i] + "<br><input type='button' onclick='next(" + next + ");' value='next' />")
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  That does it!